# Adding multiple buttons to JQuery header

Tags: html, jquery-mobile

How do I add 3 buttons to the JQuery mobile header? I have 2 buttons there using an input type, and a hidden  tag that doesn't get styled or show up (it's under the other two buttons).

http://jsfiddle.net/yL4tfu6q/

The JSFiddle has the two buttons inline, but we want the the last button (glossary  tag button) inline with the other two! Is this possible?

```
        <div data-role="header" style="overflow:hidden;">
        <h1>Your uploaded Info</h1>

        <a href="#" data-rel="back" data-icon="arrow-l" class="ui-btn-left" data-transition="slide" data-direction="reverse">Menu</a>
        <div id="Trending" class="ui-btn-right" data-inline="true">
            <a href="../tools/glossary.html" data-icon="gear" class="ui-btn-right" data-transition="slide" data-inline="true" data-direction="reverses">Glossary</a>
         <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal"> 
            <label for="cbTrendOn">check if trending ON</label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="cbkTrendsON" id="cbTrendOn" value= "check if trending ON" onclick="rbTrendsON()"> 
            <input type="button" name="graphTrend" id="btnGraphTrend" value="Graph Trends" onclick="btnGraphTrend()" >
        </fieldset>

    </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: The glossary button-- the one with the <a> tag.

Comment: Silly question. Didn't read the question well enough.

Comment: I edited it to fix it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work? (Please note: I'm not very familiar with jQuery Mobile)

```
<fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
      <label for="cbTrendOn">check if trending ON</label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="cbkTrendsON" id="cbTrendOn" value="check if trending ON" onclick="rbTrendsON()" />
      <input type="button" name="graphTrend" id="btnGraphTrend" value="Graph Trends" onclick="btnGraphTrend()" /> 
      <a href="../tools/glossary.html" data-icon="gear" class="ui-btn" data-transition="slide" data-inline="true" data-direction="reverses">Glossary</a>
</fieldset>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yL4tfu6q/2/

Comment: Thank you! I guess I kept the class on accident, totally forgot about it!

Comment: Np. I'd recommend deleting the question as it was a simple typo.

Comment: Apparently I cannot, because it was flagged.

Comment: Not I! Sorry, that's why I suggested it. I was hoping you'd be able to get to it first. [No big worries though.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/234575/what-happens-to-reputation-when-someone-flags-a-post).